# Error when using apply and t-test

Tags: r, runtime-error, apply

I can't find the bug in my code, and/or the flaw in my logic. I have a matrix, `X`, of 0's and 1's and a vector `y` of continuous values and I want to do a 2 sample t-test in `R` where the rows of `X` indicate the different groups of `y`.

For example:

```
x = matrix(rbinom(60,1,.5),ncol=10)
y = abs(rnorm(ncol(x)))

apply(x,1,function(x,y=y)t.test(y[x==1],y[x==0]))
```

So using this code I would have expected to get 6 t-tests where each row of `X` corresponds to the two groups of `y`. However, I get this error when I run my code:

```
 Error in t.test(y[x == 1], y[x == 0]) : 
  promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?
```

Can someone explain the error and modify my code to get what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from your re-use of variable names in your function arguments. This should work:

```
apply(x,1,function(x.f,y.f=y)t.test(y.f[x.f==1],y.f[x.f==0]))
```

Comment: why not remove the second argument?

Comment: `apply(x,1,function(x)t.test(y[x==1],y[x==0]))`

Comment: I think it's more clear what's going on this way. Referencing variables inside a function that are not in its scope is not good style imho.

Comment: Passing extra arguments that way is pretty ugly, useless, and confusing imho

Comment: Good thing its only your opinion.

Comment: how about `apply(x,1,function(x,y)t.test(y[x==1],y[x==0]),y=y)`, in the spirit of ira's answer?

Comment: @DavidHeckmann I am using `pvalue = lapply(ans,`[`,c("p.value"))` to get the p-values but is there a way to strip away the labels so that it looks like a nice vector of only numbers?

Comment: you mean `pvalue = sapply(ans,function(x)x$p.value)`?

Comment: yup! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
apply(x,1,function(x,z)t.test(y[x==1],y[x==0]),y)
```

If you want to use the second argument within the function, you should also pass it to `apply`

Answer (score 1):

Following works:

```
> apply(x,1,function(a)t.test(y[a==1],y[a==0]))    
[[1]]
```

You should give better names to data in data.frames and vectors so that x and y etc can be used as general variables. Also there is no need to send y to the function since it will be same for all tests.

Output:

```
        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  y[a == 1] and y[a == 0]
t = 0.43835, df = 5.377, p-value = 0.6782
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.6356057  0.9036413
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
0.5807408 0.4467230 


[[2]]

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  y[a == 1] and y[a == 0]
t = -0.80208, df = 5.5382, p-value = 0.4555
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.0985419  0.5644195
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
0.4337110 0.7007722 


[[3]]

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  y[a == 1] and y[a == 0]
t = 0.58194, df = 7.3884, p-value = 0.5779
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.5584942  0.9283034
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
0.6329878 0.4480832 


[[4]]

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  y[a == 1] and y[a == 0]
t = 1.1148, df = 4.8236, p-value = 0.3174
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.4919082  1.2308641
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
0.7622223 0.3927443 


[[5]]

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  y[a == 1] and y[a == 0]
t = 0.23436, df = 5.5539, p-value = 0.8231
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.7818960  0.9439901
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
0.5729543 0.4919073 


[[6]]

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  y[a == 1] and y[a == 0]
t = -1.015, df = 7.9168, p-value = 0.3401
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.0152988  0.3954558
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
0.3855747 0.6954962
```

For only p values:

```
> apply(x,1,function(a)t.test(y[a==1],y[a==0])$p.value)
[1] 0.6781895 0.4555338 0.5779255 0.3173567 0.8231019 0.3400979
```